# how to localize a application bar in wp7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

is it possible to localize the application bar?

i made the tutorial on msdn how to localize a application and everything was find. but the method with:

```
{Binding Localizedresources.Today, Mode=OneWay}
```

dont work on the app. bar

what can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use a 3rd party solution like James Cadd suggested, you may create the application bar from your code-behind and using your resources to fill-in the Text-property:

```
public MainPage() {
  InitializeComponent();
  Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
}

void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  BuildApplicationBar();
}

private void BuildApplicationBar() {
  ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

  var appBarButtonAdd = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/img/add.png", UriKind.Relative)) { Text = AppResources.ABAdd };
  appBarButtonAdd.Click += newEntry_Click;
  ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(appBarButtonAdd);

  var appBarMenuReview = new ApplicationBarMenuItem(AppResources.ABMarketplace);
  appBarMenuReview.Click += review_Click;
  ApplicationBar.MenuItems.Add(appBarMenuReview);
}
```

Comment: if you have multiple different application bars, this can become ugly rather quickly. I wonder why the binding method does not work for the application bar.

edit: found why: http://blogs.codes-sources.com/nicolas/archive/2010/08/19/wp7-comment-avoir-une-applicationbar-bindable.aspx

Comment: The above approach will not work when you want to use more than one ApplicationBars within a page which show/hide on different-2 events. What is the solutions to show multiple ApplicationBars from the codebehind having the localization ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few implementations of a bindable ApplicationBar for WP7, you might try one of these:

http://www.maxpaulousky.com/blog/archive/2011/01/10/bindable-application-bar-extensions-for-windows-phone-7.aspx

http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2011/02/case-for-bindable-application-bar-for.html

Answer (score 0):

You haven't included much to work with, but I wrote [a pretty good (I think) blog](http://hopnet.mobi/website/Blog/tabid/227/EntryId/1/Localized-Windows-Phone-App-Start-to-Finish.aspx) on the subject, including code from start to finish on localizing an app.  It covers localization from start to finish, with screenshots and downloadable code, including the application bar.